# Is there any wordpress function to update a random post every 10 minutes?

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I' m looking for a function which can be inserted in wordpress theme function.php  , when inserted , i want it to update a random post  (which is already posted ) every 10 minutes .

can this be done through cron job  or by simple writing a php code in function.php.

Comment: what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Something like ....                                                   <?php $my_post=query_posts('showposts=1&orderby=rand'); wp_update_post( $my_post ); ?>

i m not sure , my php knowledge is very limited !

Comment: Could you elaborate so we can have a wider idea of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`wp_schedule_event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) to schedule recurring tasks. The smallest precision it normally supports is "hourly" but you can use [`wp_get_schedules`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_schedules) to create a custom "ten_minutes" interval.

Or, you could use [`wp_schedule_single_event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event) to just trigger the event once and have that scheduled task schedule the next event ten minutes later.